# How to show another card using CardLayout?

Tags: java, menubar, cardlayout

This question may have been answered heaps, but I'm trying to get my menu bar working with my CardLayout, unlike buttons from other questions; I've been stuck on this for a very long time.

I currently am trying to get three separate classes working together,

1. CardLayout class - Sets up the frame and adds the necessary panels to the frame. This class is also meant to show different cards.
2. MenuBar class - This class sets up a very minimal menu bar, which I attach to my frame in my CardLayout class. I simply pick a menu item from here and add an action listener for my third class.
3. MenuActionListener - This class is responsible for listening for the action event created when I select a menu item from my menu bar. When a certain item is selected, the corresponding card will be shown, in which is the handed back to my CardLayout class to switch cards.

My CardLayout class:

```
public class CardLayoutExample {
    private CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout(20, 20);
    private JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(cardLayout);

    private MyPanel panel1;
    private MyPanel panel2;
    private MyPanel panel3;

    private void displayGUI()
    {        
        MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Card Layout Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        contentPane.add(createPanel(Color.BLACK), "Panel 1"); 
        contentPane.add(createPanel(Color.RED), "Panel 2");   

        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);   
        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar.getMenuBar());
        frame.pack();   
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public JPanel createPanel(Color color) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(color);

        return panel;
    }

    public void redCard() {
        System.out.println("Selected Red Item");
        cardLayout.show(contentPane, "Panel 2");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new CardLayoutExample().displayGUI();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

MenuBar class:

```
public class MenuBar {

    private JMenuBar menuBar;
    private MenuActionListener mal;

    public MenuBar() {
        mal = new MenuActionListener();
        System.out.println("menuBar");

        //Creates a menubar for a JFrame
        menuBar = new JMenuBar();

        //Define and add drop down menu to the menubar
        JMenu mainMenu = new JMenu("Main Menu");
        menuBar.add(mainMenu);

        //Define addMenu items
        JMenuItem addRedItem = new JMenuItem("Red");
        addRedItem.addActionListener(mal);

        //Add main menu items/menu
        mainMenu.add(addRedItem);
    }

    public JMenuBar getMenuBar()
    {
        return menuBar;
    }
}
```

And my MenuActionListener class:

```
public class MenuActionListener implements ActionListener {

    public void redActionPerformed() {
        new CardLayoutExample().redCard();
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
        String command = e.getActionCommand();
        System.out.println(command);

        switch (command) {

            case "Red":
                redActionPerformed();
                break;

            default:
        }
    }
}
```

When I select the Red item from my menu bar, the following line of code is triggered: `System.out.println("Selected Red Item")`, then the code to show my red panel is run through, however, the card does not change at all?

I've been trying forever to try and get my menu bar working with changing out my cards; how can I fix my code up so that I can properly display the card I want?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `MenuActionListener.redActionPerformed` method. You are creating a whole new `CardLayoutExample` object and using it instead of the existing one that represents the actual UI. The simplest way to fix this is to make your Menu classes nested ones so that they get an implicit reference to the outer `CardLayoutExample` class. Then in `redActionPerformed` you can just call `redCard()` directly. Otherwise you will need to pass a reference to the CardLayoutExample object down to the MenuActionListener class. See below for the complete example:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class CardLayoutExample {
    private CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout(20, 20);
    private JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(cardLayout);

    private final static String p1 = "Panel 1";
    private final static String p2 = "Panel 2";

    private void displayGUI()
    {        
        MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Card Layout Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        contentPane.add(createPanel(Color.BLACK), p1); 
        contentPane.add(createPanel(Color.RED), p2);   

        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);   
        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar.getMenuBar());
        frame.pack();   
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public JPanel createPanel(Color color) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(color);

        return panel;
    }

    public void redCard() {
        System.out.println("Selected Red Item ");
        ((CardLayout)contentPane.getLayout()).show(contentPane, p2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new CardLayoutExample().displayGUI();
            }
        });
    }

  // Inner Menu Bar class
  class MenuBar {

      private JMenuBar menuBar;
      private MenuActionListener mal;

      public MenuBar() {
          mal = new MenuActionListener();
          System.out.println("menuBar");

          //Creates a menubar for a JFrame
          menuBar = new JMenuBar();

          //Define and add drop down menu to the menubar
          JMenu mainMenu = new JMenu("Main Menu");
          menuBar.add(mainMenu);

          //Define addMenu items
          JMenuItem addRedItem = new JMenuItem("Red");
          addRedItem.addActionListener(mal);

          //Add main menu items/menu
          mainMenu.add(addRedItem);
      }

      public JMenuBar getMenuBar()
      {
          return menuBar;
      }

  }

  //Inner MenuActionListener class
  class MenuActionListener implements ActionListener {

      public void redActionPerformed() {
         // Call the redCard() method in outer object.
          redCard();
      }
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
          String command = e.getActionCommand();
          System.out.println(command);

          switch (command) {

              case "Red":
                  redActionPerformed();
                  break;

              default:
          }
      }
  }

}
```

Comment: Ahh, I see now. I really wanted to utilize my classes and spread them out whilst avoiding this type of class integration. Having all my classes nested into one main class seems a little messy to me, but as I read about the docs for nested classes, it says that it is the logical reason if classes are working with one other class, in which is what is happening here.

Thank you for the enlightenment, and I'll be sure to take this on board.